# MagicSuggest Move to next input on Blur

Tags: jquery, blur, multi-select

In Magic Suggest, when I use on Blur function to move focus to next normal textbox,it is not working.it automatically moves to next magicsuggest element if I didn't set any blur function.If I set blur function,it moves to the second element without moving to first.

```
chamber= $('#select28').magicSuggest({
                                expandOnFocus: true,
                                useTabKey: true,
                                autoSelect: false,
                                //resultAsString: true,
                                data: result[index].split(','),                                  
                                id:'select28'
                            });
                                $(chamber).on('blur', function (e) {
                                $("#select29").focus();

                            });
```

In this code,the focus moves to select30 element instead of select29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.I have used settimeout function and it worked.

```
$(chamber).on('blur', function (e) {
setTimeout(function(){
$("input[id='select29']").focus();
},100);
```